# Can you ignore specific versions of strongly named references?

Tags: c#, .net, reference

I am doing some addons on a product which has strongly named references. If I select *false* in *Specific Version*, the program complains that the reference is installed already.

Is there any possibility to ignore specific strongly named references?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot ignore it, but you can redirect a request from one version to another version.

See:[Redirecting Assembly Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx)

The `Specific Version` property is only applicable for references to assemblies that don't have a strong name.