# SpecificVersion=False with TFS API dll's

Tags: c#, tfs-sdk

Our web application makes heavy use of the TFS API.  We developed and compiled it with the TFS 2010 API dll's.  We also set SpecificVersion=False.

The problem is that when we deploy to a server that has TFS 2012 and not TFS 2010, we get the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=10.0.0.0,.....etc. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any way to migitate this?  TFS 2012 is installed into the GAC and the fact we are saying "SpecificVersion=False" should tell the app to use the 2012 (version 11) of the dll's instead of 2010 (version 10).  Correct??

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

Specific version [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417481/can-you-ignore-specific-versions-of-strongly-named-references) if the assembly is [strong name signed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4fa028b.aspx). Microsoft almost certainly strong-name signed their assembly.

Your website will have to make use of a [`bindingRedirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) to redirect all versions to from v10 to v11. For example:

```xml
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client"
                              publicKeyToken="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0"
                             newVersion="11.0.0.0"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Make sure to update the `publicKeyToken` to the correct value.

---

Alternatively, you could recompile the website against the v11 version of the TFS SDK to avoid the binding redirect, however then it will only work with v11 of the TFS SDK.

Comment: Yeah - I was in the middle of researching this.  It seems Microsoft should be using a publisher policy as well as they claim their 2012 SDK is backwards compatable with 2010.  However, there isn't a publisher policy that will allow references to 2010 reference 2012 instead.  I'll go with the assembly binding redirect in the app.  :)

Comment: What I am looking for now is how to specify a wildcard in the target assembly version.  For example:  newVersion="11.*.*.*" - Any idea how to do this?  I am googling, but no luck so far.  The problem is I need to reference any version of TFS 11 API.  I don't want a service pack update require a manual redeploy of the web.config just to specify the new version.  It wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: @user1060500 `newVersion` must be specific, wildcards are not allowed. `oldVersion` allows you to specify ranges, like `oldVersion="9.0.0.0-10.0.0.0"`.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  So it won't solve my problem.  I need to be able to use the latest version of major version 11 of the dll.  So, 11.0.0.1 or 11.2.8.6 as an example.  Is this configurable for a strongly named assembly reference?

Comment: @user1060500 Unless there is something I have overlooked, what you are trying to achieve is not possible.

Comment: It might not be a problem with TFS.  Microsoft keeps their publiched versions as 10.0.0.0 and 11.0.0.0 - any service pack deviations will be noted on the file version but not the version that was published in the GAC - it should always be consistent as 11.0.0.0 :)

Comment: @user1060500 That is true. Otherwise massive pain would be inflicted on developers. If they were to introduce a new version, it would be a new entry in the GAC, not update the existing one.

Comment: Yep.  From what i've seen, they also provide a publisher policy in cases where a service pack might change the version.  Example 10.2 will work with 10.4, etc.  So, I think I'm safe within a single version.  It doesn't look like they make their Major releases backward compatable via a GAC publisher policy however.  Which is fine, I'll do that in my own app config.  Thanks for the help.